# access javascript variable in page load event c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am setting session variable in `Page1.aspx` inside `document.ready` As

```
sessionStorage.setItem('PrePayAmt', 'Some Value To Be Stored');
```

**Now i want to get this value in `Page2.aspx` Page Load Event**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Get Value Here
}
```

I have declared script section in `Page2.aspx` Where i am able to get this value

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var pre_pay = sessionStorage.getItem('PrePayAmt');
        alert(pre_pay);
    });
</script>
```

I have also got one hidden variable in `Page2.aspx` As

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnPrePayAmt" />
```

Comment: How about getting the value from hiddenField in code behind??

Comment: You have to make, either post to page2, either send it on url, when you call page2.

Comment: @Aristos : Apart from that any alternative i hate to pass it as query parameter because it is amount which i am passing.

Comment: @User2012384 : do i able to access then in my `page_load` event ?

Comment: I suggest you to update the hiddenfield's value using javascript, then you'll be able to get it back in code behind.

Comment: @User2012384 : I tried that but it getting set after `page_load` event. read question once again

Comment: Oh...Sorry...just now misunderstand your question, just now did some research, according to this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488790/access-web-storage-from-server-side-possible, it said it isn't possible to access sessionstorage from code behind, but it recommend several ways to get it, see if it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were correct to try and set a hidden value that gets posted back, however if you use a sever-side asp.net `HiddenField` (i.e. `asp:HiddenField`) you need to specify a `ClientId="hdnPrePayAmt"` setting and not just `ID=`

e.g.

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ClientID="hdnPrePayAmt" />
```

as

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnPrePayAmt" />
```

will generate its own *client-side* ID for that field.

*If you view your page source in the browser you will see what is going on*